# Subcommand in dockerised app exits with `exit code 1`

Tags: linux, docker, command, exec

I have an application. The application is working on Linux, but I plan to migrate it to the docker container.

I developed some modules that can use embedded PostgreSQL instead of a regular Postgres database. It is working perfectly on my Host, but in the Docker, the process exits with code `1`.

In the application, I want to start a subprocess with the following command:

```
cmd := exec.Command("embeded-postgres")

err := cmd.Run()
```

error is:

```
exit status 1
```

no other information in stderr or stdin

I think there is some mechanism that checks if only one process is working in the container, but I cannot find any documentation. Could anyone point me in to correct direction, please? I would like to read and understand more about this.
Could anyone point

Answer (score 1):

****If you could post your Dockerfile, it would really help determine the cause, I'd love to help you debug the issue further**.** Meanwhile, here are some things that might help you with the issue.

1. You can have `cmd.Run()` output [an actual error message to stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159704/how-to-debug-exit-status-1-error-when-running-exec-command-in-golang)
2. To call `exec.Command("embeded-postgres")`, an executable named `embeded-postgres` needs to be located inside a directory in your `$PATH`, try using the full path where the executable is installed (for `file`, this would be `/usr/bin/file`). You can determine the path using `which embeded-postgres`
3. Make sure the `embeded-postgres` executable is present in your container. Docker containers have a separate filesystem and while it shares some things with the host (like the kernel), if you have `embeded-postgres` installed on your host, the container won't be able to access it. Think of `chroot` but on steroids.
4. While there isn't any mechanism that checks if only one process is running in the container, running multiple **unrelated** processes in a container is usually considered an anti-pattern.
5. I don't have much information about your use case and I definitely don't know anything about `embeded-postgres`, but I found [this Go library](https://github.com/fergusstrange/embedded-postgres). Could this perhaps be a cleaner solution instead of installing a system executable and calling it with `os/exec`?